# Google Charts - Shared label for adjacent columns with the same value

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

[image: Redundant column values]

I have a Google Chart that's showing repeated values for adjacent rows containing the same value. Is there a way to make adjacent columns share a label if the value they represent is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no standard options to prevent annotations from repeating,
but these could be easily removed

---

**1)**

if the annotation values are loaded as part of the data,
and you don't want to change how the data is loaded

use a simple routine to set the annotations to `null`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Members', {role: 'annotation'}],
    ['2015-09', 0, '0'],
    ['2015-10', 0, '0'],
    ['2015-11', 0, '0'],
    ['2015-12', 0, '0'],
    ['2016-01', 1, '1'],
    ['2016-02', 1, '1'],
    ['2016-03', 1, '1'],
    ['2015-04', 3, '3'],
    ['2016-05', 3, '3'],
    ['2016-06', 3, '3'],
    ['2016-07', 3, '3'],
    ['2016-08', 3, '3'],
    ['2016-09', 3, '3'],
    ['2016-10', 4, '4'],
    ['2016-11', 6, '6'],
    ['2016-12', 6, '6'],
    ['2017-01', 8, '8'],
    ['2017-02', 8, '8'],
    ['2017-03', 8, '8'],
  ]);

  // remove repeated annotations
  var annotationText = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    if (annotationText === data.getValue(i, 2)) {
      data.setValue(i, 2, null);
    } else {
      annotationText = data.getValue(i, 2);
    }
  }

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      alwaysOutside: true,
      textStyle: {
        bold: true,
        fontSize: 20
      }
    },
    colors: ['#0097A7'],
    hAxis: {
      slantedText: true,
      textStyle: {
        bold: true,
        fontSize: 16
      }
    },
    height: 400,
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: data.getColumnLabel(1)
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**2)**

if the annotation values are set using a DataView,
modify the `calc` function to not repeat annotations

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Members'],
    ['2015-09', 0],
    ['2015-10', 0],
    ['2015-11', 0],
    ['2015-12', 0],
    ['2016-01', 1],
    ['2016-02', 1],
    ['2016-03', 1],
    ['2015-04', 3],
    ['2016-05', 3],
    ['2016-06', 3],
    ['2016-07', 3],
    ['2016-08', 3],
    ['2016-09', 3],
    ['2016-10', 4],
    ['2016-11', 6],
    ['2016-12', 6],
    ['2017-01', 8],
    ['2017-02', 8],
    ['2017-03', 8],
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      if (row > 0) {
        if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === dt.getValue(row - 1, 1)) {
          return null;
        }
      }
      return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1);
    },
    role: 'annotation',
    type: 'string'
  }]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      alwaysOutside: true,
      textStyle: {
        bold: true,
        fontSize: 20
      }
    },
    colors: ['#0097A7'],
    hAxis: {
      slantedText: true,
      textStyle: {
        bold: true,
        fontSize: 16
      }
    },
    height: 400,
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: data.getColumnLabel(1)
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
  chart.draw(view, options);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```